# get Key and Value of HashMap in Javascript/AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, hashmap

I have this HashMap in Frontend getting from Backend:

```
 var myVar = {"24":{"amount":2,"minutes":30},"32":{"amount":3,"minutes":30}}
```

Does anyone know how I can get the keys and the values in Javascript/AngularJS?
I have tried

```
{{myVar.24}}
{{myVar.next()}}
```

but nothing works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an object in javascript and here you use number string as a key so to access the object values use this syntax **myVar[key]** ; look at the example below

```js
var myVar = {"24":{"amount":2,"minutes":30},"32":{"amount":3,"minutes":30}}
console.log(myVar['24']);
```

Comment: I would have an additional question: how to get the first key?

Comment: Try this Object.keys(myVar)[0]

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Object.keys](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) & [Object.values](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/values)

```js
var myVar = {
  "24": {
    "amount": 2,
    "minutes": 30
  },
  "32": {
    "amount": 3,
    "minutes": 30
  }
}
var getKeysArray = Object.keys(myVar);
var getValueArray = Object.values(myVar)
console.log(getKeysArray, getValueArray)
```